# wsimport: class generation error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I have a web service in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public DataTable connectoToMySql()
        {
            string connString = "SERVER=localhost" + ";" +
                "DATABASE=test;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=root;";

            MySqlConnection cnMySQL = new MySqlConnection(connString);

            MySqlCommand cmdMySQL = cnMySQL.CreateCommand();

            MySqlDataReader reader;

            cmdMySQL.CommandText = "select * from user";

            cnMySQL.Open();

            reader = cmdMySQL.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);


            cnMySQL.Close();

            return dt;
        }


    }
}
```

The generated wsdl is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s:element name="HelloWorld">
        <s:complexType />
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="HelloWorldResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HelloWorldResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="connectoToMySql">
        <s:complexType />
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="connectoToMySqlResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="connectoToMySqlResult">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax" />
                  <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax" />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorld" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorldResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="connectoToMySqlSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:connectoToMySql" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="connectoToMySqlSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:connectoToMySqlResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WebService1Soap">
    <wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:HelloWorldSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:HelloWorldSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="connectoToMySql">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:connectoToMySqlSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:connectoToMySqlSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WebService1Soap" type="tns:WebService1Soap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="connectoToMySql">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/connectoToMySql" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="WebService1Soap12" type="tns:WebService1Soap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="connectoToMySql">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/connectoToMySql" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WebService1">
    <wsdl:port name="WebService1Soap" binding="tns:WebService1Soap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:50066/WebService1.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="WebService1Soap12" binding="tns:WebService1Soap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:50066/WebService1.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I want to consume the service with java.
When I try to generate the corresponding java classes with `wsimport` I get an error:

> $ wsimport -s src -keep http://localhost:50066/WebService1.asmx?WSDL
>
> parsing WSDL...
>
> [ERROR] Property "Any" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to
>   resolve this conflict.   line 24 of
>   http://localhost:50066/WebService1.asmx?WSDL
>
> [ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error   line
>   25 of http://localhost:50066/WebService1.asmx?WSDL
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:129)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2283)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:183)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:126)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
>           at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)